# How to use Beta Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, calculator

Like the title says how do I use this. 
Especially in a case where $P(X \le 0.5)$ and harder cases where there are 2 bounds like $P(0.25 \lt X \lt 0.5)$. I am using a TI-84 graphic calculator

The question I tried to answer had X ~ Beta(3,2). Where the question was find
$P( (1/3) \lt X \lt (1/2))$
My logic was to split it in 3 different probabilities namely:
$(P(X \leq (1/2)) - P(X = (1/2)) - P(X \leq (1/3))$
Seeing as I can do the integral from 0 to 0.5 minus 0.5 to exclude it and then the whole thing minus the integral from 0 to 1/3. the answer I get is -0,216

Comment: What tools are you using? Tables, a computer, a calculator, ... ?

Comment: Sorry didn't mention that. I am using a graphical calculator at the moment

Comment: Which graphing calculator?

Comment: A ti-84plus but I am not sure if I can use that on the exam so the example I tried was done using the formulas, if you are implying that there is a function on the calculator that does it for you ;)

Comment: You should be able to use the integration function. Show us what integrand you used, and the negative answer you got, so we can figure out where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better for you to use R, SPSS or something like that to calculate that probabilities. I calculate it and get $0.2013889...$
I think your fault is calculating $P\{X=1/2\}$, because this probability is, of course, zero (beta distribution is continuous, not discrete). May be your calculator get it wrong in that calculation.

**EDIT:** But it is also quite easy to calculate directly $$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{t^2(1-t)}{B(3,2)}dt  $$
where we have $1/B(3,2)=12.$
Something similar we have to do for the $P\{X<1/3\}.$
Or even more easier just calculate the integral: $$12\int_{1/3}^{1/2} (t^2(1-t))dt. $$

How I calculate $\frac{1}{B(3,2)}$?
Like the link, that I give in a comment for Beta function, says I can calculate $B(3,2)$ like $\frac{\Gamma(3)\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(5)}=\frac{2!1!}{4!}=\frac{2}{24}=\frac{1}{12}$, so 
$$\frac{1}{B(3,2)}=\frac{1}{1/12}=12 $$

Comment: Could you show me what you did to get that answer?

Comment: Right now I have used R and the commands $pbeta(1/2,3,2)$ and $pbeta(1/3,3,2).$

Comment: See the edited answer above.

Comment: Doesn't this also include (1/3) and (1/2)? which should be excluded from the question? And what do you do to get 12?

Comment: Integral in one and only one point is zero, always! So, we have that $P\{X\leq 1/2\}=P\{X<1/2\}.$ Is it ok?

Comment: With $B(3,2)$ I denote the Beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Yes this is what I needed thank you very much!

Comment: Nicely explained. +1